# Can I pass a variable from a Jekyll template to an include then render data with that variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, for-loop, jekyll

In foo.html (a post), I have the following:

```
{% assign table_name="application" %}
{% include table.html %}
```

This assignment appears to work fine in table.html

```
{% assign tableName = table_name %}
<p>table name is: {{ tableName }}</p> # renders "table name is: application"
```

Now, I'm trying to sort through an array of data that I have defined in config.yml by doing the following:

```
{%  for header in site.table.tableName.headers %}
<th>{{ header }}</th>
{% endfor %}
```

This gives me no output whatsoever.

If I change the `for` statement to include the variable's content, not the variable, it works fine.

```
{%  for header in site.table.application.headers %}
```

This leads me to believe that it's *not* a problem with my array but that it's either a shortcoming of Jekyll, a bug in Jekyll, or I'm not accurately constructing my statements.

Any idea how I could make this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like this can be done. I had to think about it more programmatically. What seems to be happening is that Jekyll was expecting an object and I was feeding it a string.

```
{% assign tableName = "aStringName" %}
{% include table.html %}
```

so,

```
# in _includes/table.html
{%  for header in site.table.tableName.headers %}
```

was being interpreted as

```
{%  for header in site.table."aStringName".headers %}
```

When I switched to bracket notation for the object, it was perfect.

Final result:

```
{% for header in site.table[tableName].headers %}
```

or, as Jekyll sees it,

```
{% for header in site.table['aStringName'].headers %}
```